# Destruir tela ao Navegar pelo DrawerMenu em React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Tenho uma aplicação em React Native, e uso o `DrawerNavigator` como Menu para navegação, porém quando vou de uma tela para a outra, gostaria que a anterior fosse destruída.

Para quando eu voltar a ela, recarregar tudo como se fosse a primeira vez que estou a acessando, alguma ideia de como fazer isso?

Exemplo de como crio meus `stackNavigator`:

```
const StackHome = createStackNavigator({  home: {
screen: Object.assign(home,
  {
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => (
      Object.assign({
        title: "Home",
        headerLeft: <DrawerIcon navigation={navigation} />,
        headerRight:<View></View>
      }, navigationOptions)
    )
  })}}, {  navigationOptions: {
title: "Inicial",
drawerIcon: () => (
  <Icon name="home" size={20} color="#00374c" />
)}});
```

E assim crio meu `DrawerNavigator`:

```
const drawMenu = createDrawerNavigator({  StackHome, StackPessoas},{
initialRouteName: 'StackHome',}, {
drawerPosition: 'left',
drawerBackgroundColor: 'red',
drawerWidth: 200, });
```

Eu possuo várias Const criando `StackNavigator`, e passo todas como parâmetros no `Drawer` para adicionar no Menu.

Porém não consigo destruir uma tela quando saio dela e navego para outra.

Comment: Poderia adicionar alguma amostra de código para entender-mos melhor o seu problema? Tenho trabalhado bastante com react-native-navigator, quem sabe eu possa te ajudar....

Comment: @Marconi editei minha questão acima e adicionei o stack e o drawer navigator que estou usando para minhas navegações, se puder me dar uma ajuda com isso. Obrigado desde já

Comment: Use o [reset](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html#reset), é exatamente o que precisa. Senão conseguir eu posto uma resposta.

Comment: Não estou conseguindo usar o reset porque tenho diferentes 'StackNavigator', então cada um tem um index começando do zero, consigo usar o reset quando tenho todas as rotas dentro de um 'StackNavigator', porém com um para cada rota não estou conseguindo. Tenho como retorno o erro :  'ExceptionsManager.js:74 Error: Error: There is no route defined for key saldocc.
Must be one of: 'home' '.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver meu problema apenas adicionando a propriedade `unmountInactiveRoutes: true` diretamente nas propriedades do `DrawerNavigator`, assim toda vez que mudo de tela, ele desmonta a tela que estava aberta anteriormente.
Demorei muito para achar essa propriedade, mas no fim me serviu muito bem para desmontar a tela anterior.

```
const drawMenu = createDrawerNavigator({ 
  StackHome, StackPessoas
},{
   unmountInactiveRoutes: true,
   initialRouteName: 'StackMain'
  },{
     drawerPosition: 'left',
     drawerWidth: 200,
    }
);
```